# Why after that I quit a Spring Boot application in a Linux shell (by CTRL+Z) a process still listen on the 8080 port? (the port used by my application

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application running it on a Linux machine.
It is a batch application containing **Spring Boot Admin** tool listening on the 8080 port.

I have the following "problem": I run it into my shell for the first time using this command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

it correctly start and I can access to the **Spring Boot Admin** tool panel at this address **http://localhost:8080/**

Supse that I stop my batch application execution clicking **CTRL+Z** on my keyboard, so the Spring Boot application is now stopped and I obtain this output message:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 mvn spring-boot:run
```

Ok, now if I run again my application by the same start command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

now I am obtaining this error message:

```
Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

So if I perform this command to find the process that is listening on port 8080:

```
andrea@ubuntu:~/git/notartel-api-batch$ netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8080' 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       2      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      16269/java
```

If now that I killed the previous process I restart again my Spring Boot application it will be started without problem.

Why if I quit a Spring Boot application listening on the 8080 port (using CTRL+Z into the Linux shell), this process still listen on this port? I expected that the entire application will be killed and that nothing listen on the port

Comment: Ctrl + Z doesn't kill the application but suspend it and put it in background, use Ctrl + C if you want to abort the running application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl + Z` doesn't kill the application but suspend it and put it in background, use `Ctrl + C` if you want to abort the running application.

Answer (score 2):

I do this command in my terminal to clear the process in port 8080.

```
kill `lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 8080 | tr -s " " "\n" | sed -n 2p`
```

Ctrl+C is used to kill a process with signal SIGINT, in other words it is a polite kill .

Ctrl+Z is used to suspend a process by sending it the signal SIGTSTP, which is like a sleep signal, that can be undone and the process can be resumed again.

However when a process is suspended, we can resume it again by fg (resume in foreground) and bg (resume in background) , but I can't resume a killed process, that is a difference between using Ctrl+C & Ctrl+Z.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this

```
 mvn spring-boot:run
```

on some other terminal the process will not stop listening on port if you close your IDE.

Instead of running    mvn spring-boot:run    you can just run the Main file of the application. After that when you close your application, the port will not listen.